# How to re-direct to another page once the page is loaded completely

Tags: go

I am using go-gin and have a re-direct

```
c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, myurl1).
```

Can I add a timer and call another re-direct once the first one completes in the same handler?

```
  c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, myurl1)
  // sleep for 5 seconds
  c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, myurl2)?
```

Can I pause a handler's execution for a few seconds?

Comment: You can't pause handlers execution such way. Even if you redirect between your own pages, visitor simply will see empty screen for five seconds before he will be redirected. You can either display a page or redirect, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put inside your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/" />
```

Another solution with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      setTimeout("location.href = 'http://example.com/';",5000);
 </script>
```

your html logout page with 3-d party logout page inside

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=https://localhost:8080/login" />
    <title>Test Layout</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html
        {
            margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
        }

        #content
        {
            position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://example.com/" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is helpful but my situation is slightly different. I have a logout button which redirects me to a third-party url(not under my control) which has its own page which simply says `You have been logged out successfully` I want that as soon as I land up on this page I should be re-directed to my application's login page which is at https://localhost:8080/login

Comment: I'm afraid, that what you asking is not achievable. That 3-d party page has to redirect you back and if it is not under your control and you are not able to place code mentioned above then visitor will stuck with them at this point. As a workaround solution is to use iframe, but that's completely different story.

Comment: There is something called as iframe in HTML. Looks like its achievable using that. But not sure how..

Comment: I updated answer with rough html example of how you can do it, but that's hardly related to Go, you should rise a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect once the page is loaded, you have to do that in javascript.

The base of HTTP protocol is 1 query, 1 answer: "Get me this page" -> "Here it is".

You can't answer once to a query, and one second later and say "Oh, now you have to display this other page" (that's how the protocol was defined).

Therefore, if you want to redirect to another page after a short break, you have to insert a javascript call at the end of your file: Once the first redirection is done, then JS will execute itself, and you can put something like "Wait 5 seconds then call for this second page".